# How to export KML from points plotted in javascript Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, kml, export

I want to export a KML file from points plotted in Javascript using the Google Maps API. Is there a way to do this?

I would like the user to be able to log in and see Google Maps, then plot points on the map and finally export those points in a KML format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Example builds up the KML and shows you the RAW KML format

http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/build.php

Comment: Is there any de-obfuscated JS code for this? It does not help me if there is no explanation on how its done or how to implement it myself.

Comment: http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/PolylineEncoder.js is NOT obfuscated in fact non of the site is.